# ADO speed up to open table access

Tags: ms-access, vb6, ado

What is the best method to open a table with ADO and Access, for rs.AddNew and rs.Update, based on the speed for writing data?

Do I need to use a particular cursor or a particular method?

I use an ADO connection to Jet from VB6.

Comment: This is not a trivially answerable question, even less so than most naive "what is the best?" questions we see here.  There are many variables to consider: is the database shared or exclusive, are you using just one table or lots of relations between tables, what is/are the pattern(s) of use.

Answer (score 3):

My two suggestions would be:

1. Open the Recordset as `adOpenStatic` to minimize the overhead of trying to keep track of changes to the table that might be made by other users.
2. Wrap multiple `.AddNew` operations in a transaction by doing `cn.BeginTrans` before the batch of inserts, and `cn.CommitTrans` afterwards.

### Edit

In response to the comment from @Bob77, in which he said:

> Throwing Begin/End Trans around a series of arbitrary update operations doesn't provide any intrinsic performance benefit, and in most cases should make matters worse.

The following VBScript test results clearly show that wrapping a batch of insertions in a Transaction can greatly improve performance when working with Jet/ACE databases.

```
Option Explicit
Dim con, rst, t0, i, n, s
Const adUseClient = 3
Const adOpenStatic = 3
Const adLockOptimistic = 3
Const useTransaction = False

t0 = Timer
n = 1000
Set con = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
con.CursorLocation = adUseClient
con.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=Y:\adoTimeTest.accdb;"
Set rst = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
rst.Open "SELECT * FROM tbl", con, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic
If useTransaction Then
    con.BeginTrans
End If
For i = 1 to n
    rst.AddNew
    rst("ItemName").Value = "Item_" & i
    rst("SeqNo").Value = i
    rst.Update
Next
If useTransaction Then
    con.CommitTrans
End If
rst.Close
Set rst = Nothing
con.Close
Set con = Nothing
s = "Added " & n & " rows in " & Round(Timer - t0, 1) & " seconds with"
If Not useTransaction Then
    s = s & "out"
End If
s = s & " transaction."
Wscript.Echo s
```

The structure of the table [tbl] is

```
ID       - AutoNumber, Primary Key
ItemName - Text(255), Indexed (duplicates OK)
SeqNo    - Long Integer, Indexed (no duplicates)
```

**Test 1: useTransaction = False**

The [tbl] table is empty and the .addcb file has been freshly compacted.

```
Y:\>cscript /nologo adoTimeTest.vbs
Added 1000 rows in 103.9 seconds without transaction.
```

**Test 2: useTransaction = True**

The [tbl] table has been emptied and the .addcb file has been freshly compacted again.

```
Y:\>cscript /nologo adoTimeTest.vbs
Added 1000 rows in 4.9 seconds with transaction.
```

### Edit

In response to the follow-up comment from @Bob77:

> I'd try again opening the database for exclusive access.

Additional tests using ODBC and Exclusive access:

```
con.Open "Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};Dbq=Y:\adoTimeTest.accdb;Exclusive=1;Uid=admin;Pwd=;"
```

**Test 3: useTransaction = False**

The [tbl] table is empty and the .addcb file has been freshly compacted.

```
Y:\>cscript /nologo adoTimeTest.vbs
Added 1000 rows in 26.5 seconds without transaction.
```

**Test 4: useTransaction = True**

The [tbl] table has been emptied and the .addcb file has been freshly compacted again.

```
Y:\>cscript /nologo adoTimeTest.vbs
Added 1000 rows in 6.1 seconds with transaction.
```

Comment: sorry me... here my conn and my code to open table, can you change the important part of this lines?

Comment: Set RS3 = New ADODB.Recordset RS3.CursorLocation = adUseServer RS3.Open "ASS_MF_EC", CONN, 3, adLockOptimistic, adCmdTable Set CONN = New ADODB.Connection With CONN .ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\ASS_MF\DATABASE\BMAT.mdb;Persist Security Info=False" .CommandTimeout = 0 .CursorLocation = adUseClient .Open

Comment: @user1579247 If you want to add some code to your question, click the [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/16034708/edit) link immediately below the tags for your question and then paste the code in there.

Comment: 'code'Set RS3 = New ADODB.Recordset RS3.CursorLocation = adUseServer RS3.Open "ASS_MF_EC", CONN, 3, adLockOptimistic, adCmdTable 'code'

Comment: Throwing Begin/End Trans around a series of arbitrary update operations doesn't provide any intrinsic performance benefit, and in most cases should make matters worse.  This isn't what a Transaction is for.  Static cursors have their place but this isn't some magical ideal cursor type.

Comment: @Bob77 I have edited my answer. You may find the test results interesting.

Comment: I'd try again opening the database for exclusive access.

Comment: @Bob77 I have updated my answer again. Exclusive access narrows the gap, but using a transaction still wins.

Comment: Thanks for this 9yrs later! (Btw.: you have typos: addcb -> accdb)