# VB6 Ms Access Database Editing large amount of records

Tags: ms-access, vb6

I need to process hundreds of thousands of records with VB6 and an MS Access database. I iterate through the recordset and edit each record. However it takes a lot of time to do so. Creating a database with the same amount of records using the Addnew and Update methods works much faster.

I will greatly appreciate if anyone shows me any code sample or just a strategy.

Here is the code

```
Data1(1).RecordSource = "Select * from TABLE order by Field_A ASC"
Data1(1).Refresh
If Data1(1).Recordset.RecordCount > 0 Then
    Data1(1).Recordset.MoveFirst
    Do
        Data1(1).Recordset.Edit
        Data1(1).Recordset.Fields("FIELD") = Sort_Value
        Data1(1).Recordset.Update
        Data1(1).Recordset.MoveNext
    Loop Until Data1(1).Recordset.EOF = True
End If
```

It is really quite quite simple. The real thing is, I forgot to mention, that tha HDD of the computer constantly reds/writes. This is actually the problem. With such a heavy load there is no way not to affect performance.

I first thought that the recordset generated by the query, keep in mind that we hane 1-2 Million records, causes this problem. I guess it resides on some temporary place on the hard drive and on in RAM. And so executin .Edit and .Update might be a problem in first positioning the cursor at the right place and then writing.

Don't know for sure. Probably there would be an expert to show me a way out.

Btw. I also tried with replacing the
                    Loop Until Data1(1).Recordset.EOF = True
statement with a fixed length cycle, because I also read, that this checking for Recordset.EOF also slows down performance.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: sharing your code, UPDATE statement etc. will be helpful

Comment: Using a Transaction rather than writing the updates each time will be significantly faster, see my example answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12930603/vba-to-insert-many-records-into-access-db-fast/12931324#12931324

Comment: I've started a bounty for you because I'm curious about this myself.  If you can edit your post to include code you're currently using, it might help people to find your code's weaknesses.

Comment: It's really difficult to say how you should improve the speed of what you're doing if you don't show (or at least *tell*) us what you're doing in the first place. "How can I make my code faster? I'm not going to show it to you, or even tell you what it does exactly. Can you help me?"

Comment: Just a question; can you tell us if the table has any indexes or key fields, and, if so, which fields are they?

Comment: +1 for using a transaction as @MattDonnan suggests. The test results [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16034708/ado-speed-up-to-open-table-access/16035406#16035406) are for inserts, but a transaction can speed up batches of updates too.

Comment: Apparently you are using a Data control with DAO to update your records. Get rid of that data control and just use plain Recordsets. Also remove the `Order By` if not needed. Then retry.

Comment: BellyMark - Can you check shareef's answer and see if it speeds up your process? if so, please give him the Accepted Answer checkmark so I can award the bounty. If not, please let us know that too. Thanks!

Comment: @Johnny, I have the feeling we won't hear from him until he get back to work in a few hours. Once we get more details on where he's getting **Sort_Value**, the better we can help him.

Comment: Hi again!Sorry for the interrupt, but some thing kept me away. I forgot two important thing to mention:1. Indexing won't quite work for me, because there is really a lot of data, dynamically generated, so once a set of data is processed it is rarely come back to. 2. More important- I apologize again for forgetting to mention, is that records must be iterated through, because task is to take into account the adjacent records values.

Comment: You can update based on adjacent record values using a query too.  Depending on the data it may require a subquery though.  I think it would be worth it for you to post an example of the data and result you're looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created a table called `test` with the fields `n` and `f(n)`

Timed 3 different update subroutines
 - recordset without transaction
 - recordset with transaction
 - update query

```
Sub updateFunction_noTrans()
    Dim rs As Recordset
    Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("test")
    rs.MoveFirst
    Do Until rs.EOF
        rs.Edit
        rs("f(n)") = rs("n") + 1
        rs.Update
        rs.MoveNext
    Loop
End Sub
```

This is basically what you are doing, a straight recordset while editing a field

```
Sub updateFunction_yesTrans()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim commitSize As Long
    Dim rs As Recordset
    commitSize = 5000
    Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("test")
    DBEngine.Workspaces(0).BeginTrans
    rs.MoveFirst
    Do Until rs.EOF
        rs.Edit
        rs("f(n)") = rs("n") + 1
        rs.Update
        rs.MoveNext
        i = i + 1
        If i = commitSize Then
            DBEngine.Workspaces(0).CommitTrans
            DBEngine.Workspaces(0).BeginTrans
            i = 0
        End If
    Loop
    DBEngine.Workspaces(0).CommitTrans
End Sub
```

This is the same idea but with transactions.  I commit 5000 records at a time as there was some limit established around 9k-10k per commit.  You can edit this I believe by going into the registry.

```
Sub updateFunction_updateQuery()
    CurrentDb.Execute ("UPDATE test SET test.[f(n)] = [n]+1;")
End Sub
```

This is faster than any of the recordset methods.  E.g. on around 2 million records it took ~20 seconds without transactions, ~18-19 seconds with transactions, ~14 seconds with the update query.

This all is under the assumption that the field to be updated depends on values calculated from other fiends within that records

To really speed up these kind of actions, sometimes it is dependent on the situation and more detail is needed if this doesn't apply.

Edit: Used old core 2 duo machine + no indices on the fields

Comment: +1 for suggesting a transaction. If the field being updated had an index on it then I would expect to see a significant improvement. You could also avoid editing the registry by using a statement like `DBEngine.SetOption dbMaxLocksPerFile, 300000` in the VBA code, and then you could increase your `commitSize` to ~250,000.

Comment: @Gord, actually the opposite was true. I've been playing with this for a few hours now and had several different test already written. For 1 million records, no index, I get 11 seconds with or without using transactions. For an indexed field (text), I get 27 sec using transactions & 25 sec without transactions. Btw, commit size was 5000.

Comment: Thank you for taking the effort to eve test your code. really appreciate it. But one question- what is the maximum commit size available?

Comment: I haven't attempted to see what the max level is.  @GordThompson's comment indicates 250k is possible.  I personally don't think there is a benefit to transactions from a speed point of view and that the main benefit is the ability to roll back changes etc.

Answer (score 1):

My only suggestion, which may not work in your case, is to do mass updates using an update query.

Three cases where this could work:

If **Sort_Value** can be calculated from the other fields, that's a simple UPDATE query, but I'm sure you would have already seen that.

If **Sort_Value** can be calculated from other records (like previous record), then you can probably write a more complex UPDATE query (I've seen some pretty complex queries posted here).

Lastly, if the **same Sort_Value** is being applied to a lot of records, then you can issue an UPDATE query based on those records. So, if **Sort_Value** could be 10 different values, then all your updates would be done in 10 UPDATE queries.

---

If you tell us where you get the **Sort_Value**, we might be able to help you further.

---

Here's some things that **DO NOT** work to speed up the edit/update commands, according to my testing. This is was all done using a table of 10,000 records, with 1,000,000 updates.

- RS(1) instead of RS("name"). This was suggested on another site and
  actually increased time by 20%. (25 sec / 21 sec)
- BeginTrans/CommitTrans made no difference on an un-indexed field, and
  was 1% faster on an indexed field. (un-indexed: 11 sec [w/ trans] /
  11 sec, indexed: 23 sec [w/ trans] / 25 sec) *
- Individual SQL statements. (86 sec)
- Parameter querydef. (43 sec)

*Corrected result.

---

Code for the BeginTrans/CommitTrans test.

```
Sub CommitTest()
   Dim C As String
   Dim I As Long
   Dim J As Long
   Dim RS As Recordset
   Dim BegTime As Date
   Dim EndTime As Date
   BegTime = Now()
   Set RS = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("tblTest")
   For J = 1 To 200
      RS.MoveFirst
      DBEngine.Workspaces(0).BeginTrans
      For I = 1 To 5000
         C = Chr(Int(Rnd() * 26 + 66))
         RS.Edit
         RS("coltest") = C
         RS.Update
         RS.MoveNext
      Next I
      DBEngine.Workspaces(0).CommitTrans
   Next J
   EndTime = Now()
   Debug.Print DateDiff("s", BegTime, EndTime)
End Sub
```

Comment: +1 for the testing, but YMMV. For my particular test case -- one DAO Recordset update for each row in a table with 1 million rows -- using a transaction always improved performance, but only by about 17%.

Comment: Thanks. I actually corrected my results as I didn't do a fair test (accidentally) with the BeginTrans/CommitTrans. Still only 1% faster on an indexed field. I posted the code I used above. Let me know if you see why your test was so much faster.

Comment: Ya basically I think it comes down to avoid recordsets and use queries when possible.  No matter how we optimize recordsets doesn't come close to querydefs.

Comment: I agree. I can't think of any cases where **Sort_Value** can't be calculated somehow within a query, even if it calls an outside function.

Answer (score 1):

While it may be necessary in some cases, iterating through recordsets in order to update a field should be avoided.

The sensible thing to do, which is much more effective, would be to write an SQL update query.

If your table is so big, you must be careful with the election of your indexes, specially the primary key.

Then, you can divide the data based on your PK, and update all the records in the first set, then in the second, third...

```
 UPDATE super_big_table
 SET Field_A = some_function_to_make_it_sort_value
 WHERE myPrimaryKey BETWEEN ( left_boundary AND right_boundary )
```

You repeat this (by code) for all the divisions you have made in your table.

Now, the question is- can you think of an Access function which creates the required Sort_value?

Note that if Field_A is your primary key, then you shouldn't change it. Otherwise, all your table would be rearranged each time you updated a few records, which would be a lot of work for your HD / processor. In this case, you should have a different PK, and create an index on Field_A, not PK.

Answer (score 0):

To enhance performance you can use `UpdateBatch` method of ADODB Object. But to use this feature, it requires:

1. `adOpenStatic` cursorType *and*
2. `adLockBatchOptimistic` LockType

on the recordset object.
Additionally you can also use `adUseClient` CursorLocation to have load on the client instead of the server during the operation.

To go further, refrain from using `rec.EOF` test. You should instead use for loop starting from `1 to rec.RecordCount`

> `Worth mentioning:` It is unreliable to read `rec.RecordCount` until ADODB has traversed all records. So do a `MoveLast` and `MoveFirst` to ensure correct recordcount.

Use following code as a hint:

```
set con = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
con.Provider = "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0"
con.Open(Server.Mappath("MyShopDB.mdb"))
set rec = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.recordset")
sql = "SELECT * FROM Employees"

rec.CursorLocation = adUseClient
rec.CursorType = adOpenStatic
rec.LockType = adLockBatchOptimistic

rec.Open sql, con

if not rec.EOF then            ' rescue no records situation
    rec.moveLast               ' let it see all records
    rec.moveFirst
end if

cnt = rec.RecordCount          ' avoid reading each time in loop test

if cnt > 0 then
    for i = 1 to cnt
        rec.Fields("FIELD").value = Sort_Value
        '...
        '...
        '...
        rec.MoveNext
    next i
    rec.UpdateBatch
end if

rec.Close
con.Close
```

It has been quite longer than 3 years when I switched from `VB` to `PHP`. Might be missing some tracks here. `Please note:` I have not executed this code yet. It may contain minor issues, however this should be sufficient for indication purpose.

**You can also try to split batch into fragments to see effects on performance.**